# Installing the Express Application Generator using npm

Tags: node.js, json, express, npm

**unable to install these package using npm: npm install eslint --save-dev  , npm install -g express-generator** 
Both time give same error :**

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.2.13":{"name":"mini'
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T15_20_40_810Z-debug.log

but while installing another package npm install express  it successfully installed

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to clean npm cache and then reinstall the packages

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install eslint --save-dev
npm install -g express-generator
```